# Пара простих питомих відповідників до "mute" - "unmute"

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, дієслова, словотворення

[**Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови 2010 (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)**](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=mute&dicts=4&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) подає переклад дієслова *mute* наступним чином:

> **mute** 2. сти́шувати//сти́шити, приглу́шувати//приглуши́ти
> *(сурдиною тощо)* [mjuːt]

За тлумаченнями, що їх подає **СУМ-11**, обидва варіанти мають підхожі визначення:

> **ПРИГЛУШУВАТИ**, ую, уєш і рідко **ПРИГЛУШАТИ**, аю, аєш, недок., **ПРИГЛУШИТИ**,
> глушу, глушиш, док., перех. 1. Зменшуючи силу якого-небудь звуку,
> робити його мало чутним або зовсім нечутним.

> **СТИШУВАТИ**, ую, уєш і рідко **СТИШАТИ**, аю, аєш, недок., **СТИШИТИ**, шу, шиш,
> док., перех. 1. Робити тихішим, не дуже чутним, приглушувати (звук,
> шум і т. ін.).

Оскільки жоден зі словників проєкту **e2u** [не містить](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=unmute&dicts=4&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) перекладу терміну *unmute*, доводиться створювати антонім.

Спираючись на опис префіксальних моделей дієслівного термінотворення у публікації [Специфіка префіксів ВІД- і РОЗ- у дієслівних термінах зі значенням «зворотна дія» (А. Руссу)](http://esnuir.eenu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/7422/1/34.pdf), найближчими за сенсом моделями до слів *приглушувати* та *стишувати* вбачаються модель 1.3.б з префіксом *від- (віді-,од-,оді-)* та модель 2.3 з префіксом *роз- (розі-)*:

> 1.3.б. «Позбавляти / позбавити об’єкт від певної властивості» – для перехідних дієслів

> 2.3. «Позбавляти /позбавити об’єкт від певної властивості»

Але проблема в тім, що пошук у [**ГРАК v8**](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first_form) за запитами [*відтиш**](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&corpname=grac8&corpus-search-form=true) та [*розтиш**](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&corpname=grac8&corpus-search-form=true) не надає жодних знайдень, так само, як і тотожні пошуки у [**ВЕСУМ**](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/) ([*відтиш**](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&all_forms=on), [*розтиш**](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&all_forms=on)) та у словниках проєкту **r2u** ([*відтиш**](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), [*розтиш**](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88*&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)).
Із гіпотетичним антонімом *розглушувати* та сама ситуація: [**ГРАК**](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88*&corpname=grac8&corpus-search-form=true), [**ВЕСУМ**](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88*&all_forms=on) та [**r2u**](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88*&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Отже, постає питання: який з простих відповідників точніше передає значення *mute* та яким чином утворити до нього антонім, щоб така пара якомога повніше відповідала вимогам **ДСТУ 3966-2009** до вдалих термінів (пункт Г.2 додатку Г)?

> Додаток Г
>
> <…>
>
> Г.2 Предметні сфери і властиві їм поняття різноманітні
> та багатогранні. Але є спільні ознаки, які визначають суть будь-якого
> терміна як лексичної одиниці, якою позначено певне поняття. Щоб
> виконувати свої функції, термін має задовольняти такі вимоги:
>
> — системність (Г.2.1);
>
> — відповідність лексичного значення терміна позначеному ним поняттю (Г.2.2);
>
> — однозначна відповідність терміна поняттю (Г.2.3);
>
> — раціональна стислість (Г.2.4);
>
> — стилістична нейтральність (Г.2.5);
>
> — словотворча (дериваційна) здатність (Г.2.6);
>
> — мовна правильність (Г.2.7);
>
> — переважність рідної мови (Г.2.8);
>
> — згармонізованість (Г.2.9);
>
> — наявність визначення поняття (як виняток є терміни без визначення поняття) (Г.2.10).

Comment: KDE і Microsoft перекладають це як «вимкнути звук/мікрофон» і «увімкнути звук/мікрофон». Було б добре придумати коротший переклад, але це напевно буде щось нове, а не широковживане.

Comment: Дякую за коментар, він наштовхнув мене на необхідність уточнення вимог до цієї пари термінів, тож я відредагував питання. Так, мене цікавлять саме прості відповідники, що відповідають вимогам ДСТУ 3699-2009 до вдалих термінів

Answer (score 2):

Здається, таких відповідників наразі не існує. Я теж досліджував це питання, коли працював у локалізації програмного забезпечення. Тож рекомендую до використання «Вимкнути/увімкнути звук». «Стишити/Розтишити» звучить, на мою думку, непогано, але оскільки такі терміни зараз ніде не використовуються великими корпораціями, я б не радив їх уводити задля запобігання скарг користувачів на незрозумілість інтерфейсу.

Comment: На жаль, «Вимкнути/увімкнути звук» погано задовольняє вимогу словотворчої (дериваційної) здатності (Г.2.6), на відміну від «Стишити/Розтишити».
Цікаво якими стандартами чи рекомендаціями обумовлена ваша порада уникати  термінів через невикористання великими корпораціями.

Comment: Я загалом згоден з Andre Polykanine. Якщо ми не пишемо відразу українською, причому якісь вузькоспеціалізовані речі, а перекладаємо, причому для широкого загалу, то зазвичай ми не маємо можливості написати явний глосарій (під тим-то ми маємо на увазі те-то, а під тим-то — те-то) — і в такому випадку зрозумілість, по-моєму, важить більше за перераховані @strixaluco вимоги до термінів (власне, навіть непевен, що у випадку, про який я пишу, це взагалі називається терміном); тобто ті критерії — це добре, але якщо ми не можемо підібрати ідеальне слово(сполучення) — доведеться користуватися іншим.

Comment: Це, звісно, суто моя суб'єктивна думка. Можу помилятися.

Answer (score 1):

Власне *mute* можна перекласти як *німий* або, щоб було дієслово, *знемовити*. Але якщо треба ще й антонім, то тоді на думку спадають лише *мовний/безмовний*.

Comment: Дякую. Я уточнив вимоги до пари термінів і відредагував питання, тож можливо ви забажаєте і відповідь відредагувати.